# Vertical Space between formula and brackets

Tags: math-mode, underbrace

I have the following; however I want to add more space between the formula and the underbrackets so that it doesn't look so squished. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
   \begin{equation}\label{eq:reprojection_error_final}
        f=\min_{\hat{P}^i, \hat{X}_j}
        \sum_{ij} \Bigl[\underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{d(\hat{P}^i \hat{X}_j, x^i_j)}_{\text{Projektionsdiff.}} + \underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{d(L_k^m - L_{k+1}^m ,\hat{X}_k^m - \hat{X}_{k+1}^m)}_{\text{3D-Punkt-Differenz}} + \underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{d(\hat{X}_0, 0)}_{\text{Ursprungsdiff.}}\Bigr]^2
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Current result:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What are the packages that you use?

Comment: @SinaAhmadi I edited the question; I'm using the mathtools package.

Comment: `MathTools`[package documentation](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/latex/mathtools.pdf) does not mention anything regarding that distance. This is the only thing provided: `\underbracket[〈rule thickness〉] [〈bracket height〉]{〈arg〉}`and `\overbracket[〈rule thickness〉] [〈bracket height〉]{〈arg〉}`.

Comment: Yes I know; but I thought somebody here might know a trick to get the spacing anyway

Comment: I can suggest using `Tikz` to manually add the brackets wherever you would like. It'll be a little bit messy but will do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `bigstrut` package: `\bigstrut[b]` adds avertical distance below the insertion point, and this distance is controlled by the value of `\bigstrutjot`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:reprojection_error_final}
    f=\min_{\hat{P}^i, \hat{X}_j}
    \sum_{ij} \Bigl[\underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{\bigstrut[b]d(\hat{P}^i \hat{X}_j, x^i_j)}_{\text{Projektionsdiff.}} + \underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{\bigstrut[b]d(L_k^m - L_{k+1}^m ,\hat{X}_k^m - \hat{X}_{k+1}^m)}_{\text{3D-Punkt-Differenz}} + \underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{\bigstrut[b]d(\hat{X}_0, 0)}_{\text{\clap{Ursprungsdiff.}}}\Bigr]^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:reprojection_error_final}
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{1.5ex}
    f=\min_{\hat{P}^i, \hat{X}_j}
    \sum_{ij} \Bigl[\underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{\bigstrut[b]d(\hat{P}^i \hat{X}_j, x^i_j)}_{\text{Projektionsdiff.}} + \underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{\bigstrut[b]d(L_k^m - L_{k+1}^m ,\hat{X}_k^m - \hat{X}_{k+1}^m)}_{\text{3D-Punkt-Differenz}} + \underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{\bigstrut[b]d(\hat{X}_0, 0)}_{\text{\clap{Ursprungsdiff.}}}\Bigr]^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Also check out `\vphantom`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
   \begin{equation}\label{eq:reprojection_error_final}
        f=\min_{\hat{P}^i, \hat{X}_j}
        \sum_{ij} \Bigl[\underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{d_{\strut}(\hat{P}^i \hat{X}_j, x^i_j)}_{\text{Projektionsdiff.}} + \underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{d_{\strut}(L_k^m - L_{k+1}^m ,\hat{X}_k^m - \hat{X}_{k+1}^m)}_{\text{3D-Punkt-Differenz}} + \underbracket[1.5pt][8pt]{d_{\strut}(\hat{X}_0, 0)}_{\text{Ursprungsdiff.}}\Bigr]^2
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```