# Reduce/tighter vertical spacing in \underbrace

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing, underbrace

Lots of questions here about increasing the vertical spacing in underbrace (e.g. [Increase vertical space beetwen underbrace bracket and content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538717/increase-vertical-space-beetwen-underbrace-bracket-and-content?rq=1) and [Vertical Space between formula and brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459143/vertical-space-between-formula-and-brackets?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but none I could find about decreasing it. The following code

```
% minimal working example (MWE)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\ring}{\text{ring}}
\newcommand{\alg}{\text{alg}}
\newcommand{\ACF}{\text{ACF}}

\begin{document} 
This also helps determine completions of ACF (ACF not complete theory, because $\mathbb C \models \ACF$ and $\mathbb F_p^\alg \models \ACF$, but the $\mathscr L_\ring$-sentence $\smash{\underbracket[0.2pt]{1+\ldots + 1}_{\scriptscriptstyle p\text{ times}}=0}$ is not satisfied by $\mathbb C$ but satisfied by $\mathbb F_p^\alg$). More explicitly: adding the characteristic $p$ sentence produces a complete theory. 
\end{document}
```

[image: produces]

I think if we can move up the underbracket, and move up the text underneath the underbracket it can all fit in the space between the lines (and definitely so if we say increase line spacing to 1.5 or something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied the `\underbracket` definition from `mathtools.sty` and did modifications at two places:

```
\bgroup \catcode`_=11 \catcode`:=11 \catcode`\@=11
\gdef\MT_underbracket_II:w[#1][#2]#3{%
  \mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##
    \crcr
      $\hfil\displaystyle{#3}\hfil$%
    \crcr
      \noalign{\kern -.5ex \nointerlineskip}% <<< negative kern here
      \upbracketfill {#1}{#2}%
    \crcr}\kern-.2ex}} % <<< added negative kern here
  \limits}
\egroup
```

If you want to have equidistant baselineskip in the whole paragraph with underbracket in it, I suggest to set `\baselineskip=1.6em`.

Edit: If you plan to use your `\myunderbracket` in the format

```
\myunderbracket[thickness]{formula}
```

(like in your example), then you can define:

```
\def\myunderbracket[#1]#2{%
  \mathop{\vtop{\ialign{##\crcr
      $\hfil\displaystyle{#2}\hfil$%
    \crcr
      \noalign{\kern -.5ex \nointerlineskip}% <<< negative kern here
      \upbracketfill {#1}{.7\fontdimen5\textfont2}%
    \crcr}\kern-.2ex}} % <<< added negative kern here
  \limits}
```

Comment: is it possible to write a new command like \myunderbracket to contain this modification?

Comment: @D.R I added the definition of `\myunderbracket` in my answer.

Comment: apologies for reopening this post, but I notice there's small extra horizontal space that \myunderbracket adds at the end, compared to \underbracket (most visible when one puts parentheses around the expression with the underbracket). Do you know why this happens, and can it be fixed?

Comment: @D.R OK, I corrected this. The first `\crcr` must follow the `##` immediately. I don't understand why this space is irrelevant in `mathtools.sty` but I don't want to examine it.

Comment: thank you very much. I suppose LaTeX sometimes baffles even the most experienced of us...

Answer (score 2):

With TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\ring}{\text{ring}}
\newcommand{\alg}{\text{alg}}
\newcommand{\ACF}{\text{ACF}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\myunder}[2]{\tikz[baseline]{\node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=base, baseline](A){$#1$};
  \coordinate (startpoint) at ([xshift=-.05em,yshift=-.3ex]A.south west);
  \coordinate (endpoint) at ([xshift=.05em,yshift=-.3ex]A.south east);
  \draw[line width=0.2pt] ([yshift=3pt]startpoint) -- (startpoint) -- (endpoint) -- ++(0,3pt);
  \node[inner sep=0pt, below=3pt of A.south]{$\scriptscriptstyle #2$};}}
\begin{document} 
With Ti\emph{k}Z:

This also helps determine completions of ACF (ACF not complete theory, because $\mathbb C \models \ACF$ and $\mathbb F_p^\alg \models \ACF$, but the $\mathscr L_\ring$-sentence $\myunder{1+\ldots + 1}{p\text{ times}}=0$ is not satisfied by $\mathbb C$ but satisfied by $\mathbb F_p^\alg$). More explicitly: adding the characteristic $p$ sentence produces a complete theory.

Compare with the ordinary way:

This also helps determine completions of ACF (ACF not complete theory, because $\mathbb C \models \ACF$ and $\mathbb F_p^\alg \models \ACF$, but the $\mathscr L_\ring$-sentence $\underbracket[0.2pt]{1+\ldots + 1}_{\scriptscriptstyle p\text{ times}}=0$ is not satisfied by $\mathbb C$ but satisfied by $\mathbb F_p^\alg$). More explicitly: adding the characteristic $p$ sentence produces a complete theory.

\end{document}
```

[image]